How do I hide rows in Sheet2 based on contents of a cell in Sheet1?
I am trying to hide rows in Sheet2 based on contents of a cell in Sheet1.
It seems to work if in the same sheet, but not if I reference a cell in another sheet.
I thought I could use a formula to populate a cell in Sheet2 with the information, but VBA does not seem to work off of the result of a formula in a cell.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

ActiveSheet.Activate

If Not Application.Intersect(Range("D4"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

    Select Case Target.Value

    Case Is = "USA": Rows("13:19").EntireRow.Hidden = True

                        Rows("5:12").EntireRow.Hidden = False

    Case Is = "CANADA":  Rows("13:19").EntireRow.Hidden = False

                        Rows("5:12").EntireRow.Hidden = True

    Case Is = "":  Rows("13:19").EntireRow.Hidden = False

                        Rows("5:12").EntireRow.Hidden = False

    End Select

End If

End Sub


You need to specify the worksheet before each instance of Rows.

Side notes: remove ActiveSheet.Activate, change Range(Target.Address) to just Target, and remove each instance of Is = 

"does not seem to work off of the result of a formula in a cell" ... you need the Worksheet_Calculate handler for this.

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Application.Intersect(Range("'Sheet1!'D3"), Range(Target)) Is Nothing Then
Select Case Target.Value
Case "USA": Rows("'Sheet2!'13:19").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                    Rows("'Sheet2!'6:12").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case "CANADA":  Rows("'Sheet2!'13:19").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                    Rows("'Sheet2!'6:12").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End Select

End If
End Sub

I changed it to this and it still is not working.

If you need to share more than a single line of code, it's best to edit your question and add it there.  As BigBen pointed out, Worksheet_Change isn't triggered by changes in cell values that are the result of a formula recalculating.

Worksheet_Change isn't triggered by changes in cell values that are the result of a formula recalculating, so you need to use Worksheet_Calculate.
Something like this:
'In sheet1 code module
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Select Case Me.Range("D4").Value
        Case "USA": ShowHide True, False
        Case "CANADA": ShowHide False, True
        Case "": ShowHide False, False
    End Select
End Sub

'hide/show rows in Sheet2
Sub ShowHide(bHide13_19 As Boolean, bHide5_12 As Boolean)
    With Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") 'for example
        .Rows("13:19").EntireRow.Hidden = bHide13_19
        .Rows("5:12").EntireRow.Hidden = bHide5_12
    End with
End Sub

